# How to get wrong escape symbol in string?

Tags: c#, regex

I need to replace in input string expressions like "\t" into characters '\t'. That is why I'm using Unescape routine.

```
        string source = "\t\t\\q\r\n";

        try
        {
            string result = Regex.Unescape(source);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            // Which one is wrong???
        }
```

I case I did a mistake and placed wrong escape symbol inside string I get ArgumentException.

My question is: How do I understand which symbol is bad? I need index of it? What is a best way of doing it?

Comment: Did that piece of code really compile?

Comment: @Fratyx: No, source string comes from user.

Comment: @Fratyx: You are right, I updated my question.

Comment: Are you only parsing basic escape sequences (that you can convert in a mere `switch`) or do you need to also unescape `\xZZ`, `\uXXXX`, `\cY` ? Also, a newline written as `"\n"` is an *escape sequence* defined in a regular string literal. A `@"\n"` is a verbatim string literal that contains 2 symbols, ``\`` and `\n` (equal to `"\\n"`). Now, what input have you got to process, and what do you need to get?

Comment: Put a `@` character in front of your source string: `string source = @"\t\t\\q\r\n";`

Comment: @Grant Winney: Unescape() routine works like this: "\t\\t\t" -> "\t\t\t" and "\t\\q\t" throws exception. That is exactly what I need. But I also want to be able to detect combination of symbols that coused the exception.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew: I need all of the them (both basic and \x, \u \c).

Comment: Ok, then you have no options but use Grant's idea, or build [your own parser](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/regex/system/text/regularexpressions/RegexParser.cs,156) :)

Answer (score 1):

Inspect the `ArgumentException` variable `ex`. It'll tell you which escape sequence caused the exception in the message, similar to this:

> System.ArgumentException: parsing "\t\t\q\r\n" - Unrecognized escape sequence \q.

One way you could get around it is to check the "source" string before trying to unescape it - there's a finite number of correct escape sequences, so you could remove invalid ones. From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The character representations it replaces are \a, \b, \e, \n, \r, \f, \t, and \v.

Comment: What if user has OS with different language? Is it really correct to do it that way?

Comment: Thank you. That is how I'm doing it now. I was just hoping that there is some other (pretty way) of doing it.